# I can only see model via a transparent grey strip

Tags: interface

I can only see the model via that strip

[image]

*Render view*
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> to clear clipping border.
or `View` -> `Clipping border`