# Opengl viewport only rendering a spot

Tags: 3d-view

I was working on a project and I don't know how but the viewport started hiding things out of a camera range... I tried deleting the camera but it did not work.. here is how it looks like:
[image: ex]
the archive:
https://1drv.ms/u/s!ApEztyCWw8odqnpUJSYRx8dbr_ni

EDIT: So, I think this is probably a glitch. I tried to open it with blender 2.8 and the problem just disappeared.. I cannot save it in 2.8 tho because I Still want to use it in 2.79b.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/121764/help-most-of-my-project-doesnt-show-but-still-renders and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53923/i-can-only-see-model-via-a-transparent-grey-strip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the **Clipping Border** active  <kbd>Alt</kbd>  +  <kbd>B</kbd> , hit the same shortcut to clear it. You can also find the command in the **View** menu in the 3D viewport header.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a clipping problem.

Properties panel (N) > View section > check your clipping settings.

If it's happening while in Camera View:

Select your camera and then enable Display > Limits.

You may need to increase the **End clipping distance** in Properties > Camera settings > Lens.

Comment: the problem is not with the camera, as I mentioned I tried deleting it and the problem persists. There is this grey part that looks like a retangular spotlight and only what is inside it is being rendered in the OpenGL mode